# Adding a SimplePlanningCalendar to a UI5 app fails with `getKey` error

Tags: sapui5

When I add a `SimplePlanningCalendar` to my app, I got the following Error.

[image: SimplePlanningcalendar Error View getKey]

I added the calendar with a minimal configuration to my app.

```xml
<IconTabBar xmlns="sap.m"
    id="idCategoryMenu"
    selectedKey="Home"
    headerMode="Inline"
    stretchContentHeight="true"
    applyContentPadding="false"
    select=".onSelectCategory"
    items="{
        path: 'backend>/CategorySet',
        parameters: {
            expand: 'Reports'
        },
        sorter: {
            path: 'Sort'
        },
        templateShareable: true
    }">
    <items>
        <IconTabFilter id="myIconTabFilter" key="{backend>Uuid}" text="{backend>Name}">
            <!-- ... -->
                <SinglePlanningCalendar>
                    <appointments>
                        <unified:CalendarAppointment xmlns:unified="sap.ui.unified"
                            title="{title}"
                            startDate="{startDate}"
                            endDate="{endDate}"
                        />
                    </appointments>
                </SinglePlanningCalendar>
            <!-- ... -->
        </IconTabFilter>
    </items>
</IconTabBar>
```

When I debug the app, I come to the following line inside the `SinglePlanningCalendar.js` where a key from the given `vView` parameter is requested, but the parameter only holds a string.

[image: Source view from debugger]

Anyone else had this problem before and knows why or how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the control implementation itself in the current version (1.71.21) I use for my development.

The fix in the [commit `45696fe`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/45696fe2bc4d8bd080bc98585a27a4de1102f078#diff-00c2022ec47918ec4fa52d707c4e29dc4e6244f472344b7df0526062172647e7) is available as of UI5 1.75.x.

Since I cannot change my version, I implemented the given solution in my package:

```js
{ // Controller
    onInit: function () {
      // ...
      this.calendarTemporaryFix(); // Not needed since UI5 1.75
    },

    calendarTemporaryFix: function () {
        // SinglePlanningCalendar required from "sap/m/SinglePlanningCalendar"
        const fnSetSelectedView = SinglePlanningCalendar.prototype.setSelectedView;
        SinglePlanningCalendar.prototype.setSelectedView = function (vView) {
            if (typeof vView === "string") {
                vView = sap.ui.getCore().byId(vView);
            }
            return fnSetSelectedView.call(this, vView);
        };
    },
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The version 1.71 is still supported by [OpenUI5](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/versionoverview.html) as well as [SAPUI5](https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html). If the fix is still not available in the latest 1.71 patch version (currently 1.71.34 in OpenUI5 and 1.71.39 in SAPUI5), you might want to ask for a downport of the fix on GitHub.

Comment: Are you the author of https://answers.sap.com/questions/13426091/?

Comment: Yes I asked this question there too.

Comment: Please consider removing the duplicated question. This would help avoiding same content to be crawled by search engines.